# Post repeating with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating an infinite scroll of books (wordpress posts). 
If you see the first row of books is this one:

[image]

**But if you scroll down, after it "loads more books", then this books appears again.**

So it's always loading the books (wordpress posts) from the start, not loading the posts continuosly.

On **books home** works well as you can see [here][3].

The problem is **after entering to any book (single.php)**

Any idea where is the problem and how can I solve it?

This is the code I'm using:

```
<div id="infinite-scroll">
<div id="infite-activities">
 <div class="row">
          <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
          $args=array("post_type"=>"books","posts_per_page"=>"12");
           /*  $args["paged"]=( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; */
            $args["paged"]=$paged;
            if(is_single())
                $args["orderby"]="date";
          $books=new WP_Query($args);
           while($books->have_posts()):$books->the_post();?>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
              <div class="book-grid-img">
                  <?php $default_attr = array('class'   => "img-responsive");?>
               <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail("books-grid",$default_attr);?></a>
              </div>
              <div class="box-desc-book">
                  <div class="book-title">
                     <?php the_title();?>
                     <span><?php the_field("autor");?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="book-download">
                   <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">MORE INFO</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <?php endwhile;?>

          <div class="pagination">
             <?php
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
                    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
                    'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
                    'total' => $books->max_num_pages
                ) );
                ?>
         </div>

      </div>


<script>
jQuery('#infinite-scroll').infinitescroll({
    loading: {
    finishedMsg: "<em>No more books.</em>",
    msgText: "<em>Loading more books</em>"
    },
    navSelector     : "a.next",
    nextSelector    : "a.next",
    itemSelector    : "#infite-activities",
    debug           : true,
    dataType        : 'html',
    maxPage         : 5,
    path: function(index) {
        return "page/" + index + "/?test=1";
    }
}, function(newElements, data, url){

});
</script>
```

Comment: We don't even know what isn't working at the moment. Please clarify that.

Comment: @Daniel the posts are repeating itself if you scroll down

Comment: Your SO-Badges look like you're already having some SE eyperience. So please have again a look at the FAQs and try to clearly articulate the desired outcome in contrast to the actual outcome.

Comment: @Daniel edited. Is it better? can you help me out with the actual problem? It seems you are very interested :)

Comment: The website seems OK. What's the problem?

Comment: FYI, the "infinite scroll" you're speaking about is named "pageless". This might help as a google keyword if you need help with this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is a comb of both your pagination (not the one you are printing) and the infinite scroll JavaScript you are invoking. It works on the homepage because the ajax request you are performing is requesting like so:

```
http://www.example.com/resources/books/page/3/?test=1
```

However once you get to an inner page the request changes to something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/books/many-molts-muchos/page/2/?test=1
```

SO you can see you are making requests not to the resources/books/ zone but to to books/many-molts-muchos/ which may be confusing your pagination.  Try updating the the path return function ..

FROM:

```
return "page/" + index + "/?test=1";
```

TO:

```
return "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/resources/books/page/" + index + "/?test=1";
```

You can probably also leave off the "?test" so it would look more like:

```
return "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>resources/books/page/" + index;
```

Comment: Works perfect! thank you! britter can you please remove the links from the answer, if you want to leave it there at lease change it to bitly. Thank you!

Comment: Oook I changed it to example.com so you can see the full url, as it is in the URL that the answer lies. :)

Comment: thank you. I'll accept the bounty as soon as I can because now it says I have to wait 22 hours to give the award. thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to offset your arguments in the wp_query. This tells the query to start at a later spot than usual. The offset should be a variable of $paged * $per_page

```
$args=array(
        "post_type"=>"books",
        "posts_per_page"=>"12",
        "offset" => "24" // or whatever (page * per_page) is equal to
);
```

Comment: I have put it like that but it still repeats, the difference is that now it starts with other books :/

Comment: ahh, ignore that then. It seems like it is pulling from the link of a selector, in this case a.next. When I visit the URL of a.next http://www.infonomia.com/books/30-ideas-for-2030/page/2/" it redirects me to the current page I am on. Maybe something is screwy with the code to get the pagination.